# Android, will the socket close in service when activity destroy?

Tags: android, sockets

service code ：

```
public class AlarmListeningService extends Service{
public static final String sHost = "*.*.*.*";
public static final int sPort = 5566;
Thread thrSocket;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void onStartCommand(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, startId, startId);
    thrSocket = new thrSocket();
    thrSocket.start();
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

class thrSocket extends Thread {
    Socket mSocket;

    public void run() {

        InitSocket();

        new Thread(){  
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String msg = "";
                    while (true) {
                        int count = 0;  
                        while (count == 0) {
                             count=ips.available();
                        }
                        byte[] serverdata = new byte[count];
                        ips.read(serverdata);

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }  
            } 
        }.start();  
    }

    private void InitSocket(){
        try {
            mSocket = new Socket(sHost,sPort);
            OutputStream out=mSocket.getOutputStream();
            byte[] b_client = "client".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            out.write(b_client);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    }
}
}
```

Activity code：

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent startAL = new Intent();
        startAL.setClass(MainActivity.this, AlarmListeningService.class);
        startService(startAL);
}
```

My question is will the socket in service close when I destroy the activity
(Observation at socket server)?

And the socket will re-connection in seconds to tens of seconds (Observation at socket server too)

How could I let the socket not close when I destroy the activity?

Comment: Does the `Service` close immediately after `Activity` destruction?

Comment: I think the Service doesn't close. Because in Activity is no code to restart the Service and the socket will re-connect in seconds. But I'm sure the socket close immediately after Activity destruction ( Observation at socket server, server say socket disconnect)

Comment: Try overriding the `onDestroy()` method of the `Service` and logging something there to see if it is called.